# HashMap error for Nondeterministic finite automata (containsKey(string) incompatible?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I stumbled across some compiler-errors for my university assignment. After some time of trying to fix it, I don't really find a solution to correct them.

The following is the constructor for a program that implements a Nondeterministic Finite Automata. I am working with Hashsets and Hashmaps in this case.

```
public NFA(Set<String> states, Set<String[]> transitions, String start, Set<String> end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.active = this.start;
    Map<String, String> x = new HashMap<String, String>(); //create placeholder map

    //Insert states into map
    for (String s: states) {
        this.states.put(s, x); //Placeholder map used for this line  
    }

    //Assign transitions to corresponding states.
    for (String[] t: transitions) {
        //this line throws the error.
        if (!states.containsKey(t[0]) || !states.containsKey(t[2])) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Transition Data Corrupted!");
        } else {
            this.states.get(t[0]).put(t[1], t[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

the function call is in my readIn method which pulls the construction data for the NFA from a file.

```
result = new NFA(states, transitions, start, end);
```

The compiler-errors javac announces are the following:

> ```
> NFA.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>             if (!states.containsKey(t[0]) || !states.containsKey(t[2])) {
>                        ^
>   symbol:   method containsKey(String)
>   location: variable states of type Set<String>
>
> NFA.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
>             if (!states.containsKey(t[0]) || !states.containsKey(t[2])) {
>                                                     ^
>   symbol:   method containsKey(String)
>   location: variable states of type Set<String>
> ```

Furthermore, I get an error from the eclipse-ide:

```
The method containsKey(String) is undefined for the type Set<String>
```

Comment: I'm surprised you aren't using an IDE.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit: there's no `containsKey` method in a `Set`. Why did you expect other behavior? Did you check the [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) API before posting the question?

Comment: @Zhuinden: He does (eclipse) as stated above. However sometimes an IDE is not advisable since it solves most problems without the programmer having to reason about the origin of the problem.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Right. The reason why I was surprised is because he was using Javac, and I'm not sure what he needs Javac for if he's using Eclipse. Well, Eclipse's error message was pretty explicit.

Comment: @Zhuinden: This is sometimes useful to reproduce an error. Say some javacode doesn't compile, but the IDE passes some additional parameters to `javac`, it can be hard for other programmers to guess the parameters/environment flags/... Same with regexes, always specify if you are using `grep`, PHP,...

Comment: I usually work out the entire homework in sublime text 2. Then, to check for trivial errors, I import the .java files into eclipse. I don't really like eclipse's layout.

The reason why I used javac is, because when I googled the error, some people suggested to try using javac instead, because it might come from eclipse itself.

Also thanks again, I didn't understand the error well enough, I suppose. I probably mixed up the method declarations for the HashMap and the Set, because I checked both oracle pages simultanously when working on the program. It compiles without further errors now.

Comment: @user1016675: have you tried NetBeans? For most Eclipse programmers, NetBeans is the enemy :P, but for new programmers, NetBeans can be helpful.

Comment: @CommuSoft I worked with both NetBeans and Eclipse and I can tell you the best IDE to work between these is IntelliJ Idea (IMO).

Comment: I haven't tried it, yet. Eclipse was just the first IDE that came to mind while I talked with my fellow students about what software to use :) I'll give it a try, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I actually kinda like Eclipse, but that's because it grew on me as I was using it for the ADT plugin. For anything Java and for anyone not used to any IDEs, IntelliJ IDEA is indeed the way to go: the code completion is much smarter, and it's a better environment for Java EE and many others, better Maven integration and etc. But I dislike how it searches for errors only on compilation, and not on save, which is pretty much my only reason for still sticking to Eclipse even for other Java environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `contains(String value)` for sets. In a `Set<T>`, there is no *key-value relation*.

Comment: Oh, I totally did not notice that.. I somewhat are glad that the error was this trivial. I probably mixed up the oracle pages for the HashMap and the Set. Thanks a lot!